# AMD Module Javascript: Module Loader Error

Tags: javascript, amd

I have created this module:

```
define(function(){

    function isEmpty(stValue)
    {
        return false;
    }

    function inArray(stValue, arr)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return 
    {
        isEmpty : isEmpty,
        inArray : inArray   //Error here
    };
});
```

But I'm having an error: Module Loader Error on line inArray : inArray. Is my module correct?

Comment: which line with `inArray`? there are two.

Comment: on the return statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting automatic semicolon insertions. You are effectively returning undefined.

```
define(function(){

    function isEmpty(stValue)
    {
        return false;
    }

    function inArray(stValue, arr)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return { // correct here
        isEmpty : isEmpty,
        inArray : inArray   //Error here
    };
});
```

Comment: I'm new on this.. what should i do to correct this?